# How to split horizontally with the entire upper side in Vim?

Tags: vim

```
+---------+---------+
|         |         |
|         |         |
| window1 | window2 |
|         |         |
|         |         |
+---------+---------+
```

in window2, :sp command split as following figure.

```
+---------+---------+
|         | window3 |
|         |         |
| window1 |---------|
|         | window2 |
|         |         |
+---------+---------+
```

but I want to split following figure, in window2.

```
+---------+---------+
|      window3      |
|                   |
+---------+---------+
| window1 | window2 |
|         |         |
+---------+---------+
```

Is there any way to this way?

Comment: `:sp | winc j | vsp`, then you can re-arrange windows with `CTRL-w r` and friends.

Answer (score 1):

First, split `window2` with `:sp` or `<C-w>s`.

Then move the new split above all windows with `:wincmd K` or `<C-w>K`.

So, either:

```
:sp|winc K
```

or:

```
<C-w>s<C-w>K
```